# identityToken in Authorization header returning 401 Request Unauthorized error firebase cloud functions

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a python cloud function acting as a back-end. I'd like to call the function from my reactjs front-end.

How do I get the correct token id to pass along the authorization header? I thought I should create a firebase login function and take the userIdToken? I even gave that user manually owner privileges, and I set `allUsers` permission to `Cloud Function Invoker` (even though I wouldn't like everyone to have access to this function).

And it still gives me an unauthorised 401 error ...

The Google Cloud logs say the same thing: `Request Unauthorized`

I have console logged the token which I pass to the header and it is indeed the user.getIdToken().

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);

useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      setUser(user)
      if (user) {
        try {
          // Get the ID token for the current user
          const idToken = await user.getIdToken(true);
          setToken(idToken)
          console.log('ID Token:', idToken);
          // You can use the idToken for authentication in your backend or API calls
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error getting ID Token:', error);
        }
      }
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [auth]);
```

Request code on front-end:

```
const response = await axios.post(
        '/functionName',
        { user_input: userInput },
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${isToken}`,
          },
        }
      );
```

here's the relevant part of my main.py:

```
@https_fn.on_request()
def functionName(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    if req.method == 'OPTIONS':
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://example.web.app', 
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS', 
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type', 
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
        }
        return ('', 204, headers)
    headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://example.web.app',
        }

    try:
        data = req.json

        response_data = {...}
        return (jsonify(response_data), 200)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing question: {e}")
        return ("Something went wrong processing your question", 400)
```

Only way I get this to work is to go to google cloud test terminal and curl the metadata server for an IdToken. Then hardcode that idToken in my request, then it works for a little while before it expires ...

Comment: It seems like the auth token is of an  invalid format which results in `401 Unauthorized` as suggested in this [Document1](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#401) and [Document2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference#:~:text=If%20the%20auth%20token%20supplied%20in%20the%20request%20is%20invalid%2C%20the%20request%20is%20rejected%20with%20401%20Unauthorized%2C%20with%20an%20error%20code%20of%20UNAUTHENTICATED).

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni okay what’s valid then if user.getIdToken() is invalid format?

Comment: You can pass `forceRefresh: true` to get the new token and use that to authenticate with your backend. As explained in the [Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#getidtoken).

Comment: Have you verified that you are getting an OIDC ID Token? Edit your post and show the token.

Comment: @JohnHanley I think it is not an OIDC ID Token. I have not yet enabled OIDC as a sign in method. Can't figure out how to enable it, what do I put in the issuer url? Docs that I found aren't helpful in explaining ...

Comment: If you have not enabled authorization, then anonymous users can access your endpoint. There is no identity to fetch. Why have you have tagged `firebase-authentication`?